# relative path of resource files?

Tags: maven, apache-camel, maven-2, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

when i deploy a project to servicemix i do a "mvn install" then inside servicemix i simply do: "osgi:install -s mvn:my.package.x/proj".
now when i want to reference a file inside the package i get a "file not found exception"
in my .m2 directory the package structure inside the jar looks like this (if i unpack to look):

```
servicemixTest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
--my
----package
------processingFile.class
--resources
------xsl
---------fileForTransformation.xsl
```

now in the processing Class i need to reference the xsl file with camel like this:

```
.from(url) .to("xslt:file:./data/xsl/transformation.xsl") .process()
```

i already tried:

- ../../
- ./
- nothing ("xslt:file:data/xsl/tr...")

my question is now: "how do I find resource files inside a deployed container?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XSL file is packaged in the JAR file, you don't need the file: part in the URI.  You can just refer to the location inside the JAR directly, like this:

```
from("direct:start").to("xsl:resources/xsl/fileForTransformation.xsl").process()
```